# How to compile and deliver XBox binaries

Tags: xbox, xbox-one

I would like to port a C++ physics engine to XBox and make it available commercially as a precompiled binary for game developers.

Do I need to register as an XBox developer with Microsoft for this? Will I be compiling on Visual Studio and cross compile for XBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To be a middleware vendor for Xbox, you need to join the [registered Xbox program](https://www.xbox.com/en-US/publish).**

If your code is entirely CPU-based and makes no use of GPU/DirectX then it should be possible to build a binary that's compatible across multiple side-by-side versions of the Game OS.

- x64 native only
- Build two binaries: One with `/arch:AVX` (Xbox One) and one with `/arch:AVX2` (Xbox Series X|S).
- Use `_WIN32_WINNT=0x0A00` and `WINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_FAMILY_GAMES` to ensure you are only using the subset of Win32 APIs supported by the Game OS and PC.

There are additional considerations depending on if you are planning to ship a DLL or a static C++ library to function across the range of supported compilers, make use of the "OneCore" variant of the Visual C/C++ Runtime, and link with the appropriate umbrella library. Those details can be worked out through official support channels.

> You should review [CMakeExample](https://github.com/microsoft/Xbox-GDK-Samples/tree/main/Samples/Tools/CMakeExample) and [CMakeXboxConsoleApp](https://github.com/microsoft/Xbox-GDK-Samples/tree/main/Samples/Tools/CMakeXboxConsoleApp) on GitHub which will provide insight to how you build for Xbox using the private Microsoft GDK with Xbox extensions.

You can also make use of [UWP on Xbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/) to do initial testing and validation on the Xbox CPUs as well for the quality of your port.

**UPDATE**: See [Vcpkg now supports targeting Xbox](https://walbourn.github.io/vcpkg-now-supports-targeting-xbox/)